# $G/H \cong \mathbb{Z}$ implies existence of $K \leq G$ s.t. $K \cap H = 1$ and $HK = G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Let $H \lhd G$ and $G/H \cong \mathbb{Z}$. The claim is that there is a subgroup $K \leq G$ such that $K \cap H = 1$ and $HK = G$.

Is the following correct?

Take $a$ to be any element in a generator of $G/H$. Then $K = \left< a \right>$ will work: Clearly $K \cap H = 1$ and if $g \in G$, then $Hg = Ha^m$ for some $m$ so $g \in HK$.

It's not clear to me how $G/H \cong \mathbb{Z}$ is used. What stops this working for a general normal $H$? If $H$ isn't infinite cyclic, is the group $K$ then messed up? Would it even work for finite cyclic?

Comment: For abelian groups every short exact sequence $0\rightarrow H\rightarrow G\rightarrow \Bbb Z\rightarrow 0$ splits, since $\Bbb Z$ is *free-abelian*. So $G$ is a semidirect product, i.e., $G=HK$ with $K\cap H=1$. See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2095625/show-0-to-a-mathop-to-b-mathop-to-c-to-0-is-split-when-c-is-a-free-abeli).

Comment: @DietrichBurde It's not assumed $G$ is abelian. Will it follow from the assumptions?

Comment: You use that $K\cong\mathbb{Z}$ when you state that $K\cap H=1$. (@DietrichBurde the result is true - more generally, every map to a free group splits.)

Comment: @user1729 Oh right, I was thinking that if for example some power of $a$ equals $1$, then it is $1$ and doesn't increase the intersection, but it's only in $H$ not necessarily really $1$. And if $G/H$ is even more weird, stuff goes to $K\cap H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use $K\cong\mathbb{Z}$ when you write "Clearly, $K\cap H=1$".

For example, if $G$ is torsion-free and $G/H$ is finite, then every non-trivial subgroup $K$ has $K\cap H\neq1$. Therefore, it doesn't work for finite cyclic groups.

The more general result here is that every map to a free group $G\twoheadrightarrow F$ splits. The proof here is harder.

Answer (score 1):

Every short exact sequence of the form

$$1\to H\to G\to\mathbb{Z}\to 1$$

must be split, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is not only free-abelian but also free among *all* groups (see the comments). Therefore if $f:G\to\mathbb{Z}$ is an epimorphism and $f(g)=1$ for some $g\in G$, then $h:\mathbb{Z}\to G$ given by $h(1)=g$ is the partial inverse. So the sequence (right)-splits.

It follows that $G$ is a semidirect product of $H$ and $\Bbb Z$. So we can chose $K\cong \Bbb Z$ with $K\cap H=1$ and $HK=G$.